# Using ananimation at a random location on custom view

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi, In my app, I'm trying to make an explosion animation occur, wherever an enemy is destroyed on my custom view. What is the best way to accomplish this, because I know you can't draw an imageView onto a canvas using onDraw? How do I get the animation to play at the location of the enemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first create a list of exploding and show them one after the other using a thread and handler. For example, if you created 10 images, namely explosion-1.png, explosion-2.png...explosion-10.png then, using canvas.drawBitmap, you could make them appear one after the other until the sequence finishes using a loop.

Comment: ohhh and then put a slight delay between them using handler thank you

Comment: Exactly! I am also new to android and face these type of questions daily